# Failed to load session "gnome" on beaglebone black

Tags: ubuntu, beagleboard

Good day,
I am using a beaglebone black and have install ubuntu 13.04 on the board. Following the instructions on http://www.armhf.com/index.php/boards/beaglebone-black/ 
However i was not able to load a GUI so i did

```
    sudo apt-get install gdm xfce4 network-manager
```

This loads a GUI but when i login, it shows me "Failed to load session "Gnome" "
I have searched for soloution online and found a website http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1750430

I followed the instrustions and did the following commands

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade 
sudo apt-get purge gnome-session
sudo apt-get install gnome-session
sudo apt-get install gnome-accessibility-themes
```

However when i log in, i still get  Failed to load session "Gnome"

Does anyone know how i can solve this problem? Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem.
Did what you said and it started working.

I did another step that you did not. I run the following command also:

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-shell
```

I am connecting through RDP protocol using Windows Remote Desktop.

Hope the command help.

BR, 
Adrian.